# What is the size of nanokernel?

Tags: kernel

My kernel size is approximately 32KB.

Can I call this as nanokernel?
what is the size limitation (or range) for kernel to be called as nanokernel?

Comment: Nanokernel isn't so much about size as it is about functionality and support and architecture. That said. KeyKOS is about 100KB at runtime: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~KeyKOS/NanoKernel/NanoKernel.html

Comment: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/27005/nano-kernel

Answer (score 0):

There is no size constraint on a "nanokernel".  Ultimately, there are only two types of kernel that are considered - a microkernel which contains the minimum amount of code needed to be able to provide the functions needed for an OS, with everything else running in user space, and a monolithic kernel, which contains lots of other code like device drivers, network stacks, and file system protocols.

The term "nanokernel" and even "picokernel" were coined partly as a joke to point out the absurdity of sacrificing performance to keep everything out of the kernel.  These days nanokernel and microkernel are interchangable terms effectively.

If your kernel has any device drivers in it, it is not a microkernal, it is monolithic.